# How to read wave files one by one by sprintf command?

Tags: matlab, printf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq3iZ.jpg)The wave file are like:The first digit- speaker id, second digit-utterence id

00
01
02
03
04
.
.
.
59
I tried using

```
for m=0:5
for y=0:9
 file=sprintf('%s%d%d','E:\0 (1)\0\',m,y);
 [s,fs]=wavread(file);
end
end
```

But this gives error. Alternatively I tried

```
mypath = 'E:\\0 (1)\\0\\';
filename = sprintf([mypath '%s%d.wav'],m,y); 
[s,fs] = audioread(filename);
```

But it gave error as :

```
Function is not defined for sparse inputs.
```

Please help me.

Comment: It is not clear how the file names are built, post some examples of them.

Comment: Please edit your post,it is unclear. would you please explain what you want to do? why do you want to use sprintf? we have better functions in Matlab to read files. You can use 'fullfile' and 'sprintf' together.

Comment: I actually want to calculate MFCC features of all the 59 wav files in a single matrix. The wave file are as: 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.....so on till 59. The first digit denotes the speaker number and the second id represents the utterance number of that speaker

Comment: I have attached an image showng the wave files, in the question.

Comment: @SangeetSagar, you can use single loop with ` filename = fullfile(mypath, sprintf('%02d.wav', idx));`. please check [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/379386-i-have-lots-of-wave-file-how-do-i-read-each-one-of-them-using-sprintf-command) your question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem comes from string concatenation. But since neither your file format nor your path format are clear, this is just a sample code that performs something close to what you are attempting to do:

```
for m = 0:5
    m_curr = num2str(m);

    for y = 0:9
        file = ['E:\' m_curr num2str(y) '.wav'];
        [s,fs] = wavread(file);
    end
end
```

Set a debug breakpoint on the `wavread` line and check if the format matches your needs. If not, change it accordingly.